# What are those special orbits of a group acting on a direct product of several copies of a normal subgroup?

Tags: finite-groups, gap

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup whose order $n$ is coprime to its index $m$. I start with an arbitrary section $\sigma: G/N \rightarrow G$. Then each $g \in G$ can be written as $g = n\sigma(\bar{g})$, where $n \in N$. Let $\ \Pi = N \times \underbrace{\ldots}_{m \text{ times}} \times N$ be the multiple direct product of $N$.  Then there is a bijection between the sections $G/N \rightarrow G$ and $\Pi$. The action of $G$ on $\Pi$ is then defined by the right action of $G$ onto the sections. The orbits of $G$ can't all be of size $mn$ since the size of $\Pi$ is $m^n$. This means that there are sections whose stabilizer subgroup is non trivial. How can I find these sections, or am I wrong somewhere?

P.S. This problem is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262947/topics-in-algebra-n-herstein-exercise-from-section-2-12-question-16-page-10/)

Comment: Some of the shorter sections will correspond to complements and supplements to $N$ in $G$.

Comment: @ahulpke In the related question I took as an example the group $C9 \times Q8$  where $N = C9$. Brute force wading through $8^6$ sections is a long way to go. Isn't there a shorter way to find such a section?

Comment: How exactly do you define the image of a section $\sigma$ under the group element $h$?

Comment: @ahulpke If one regards  a  section as set $\{g_1, \ldots, g_m\}$, where for $i \neq j$ the elements $g_i, g_j$ belong to different right cosets then the image under $h$ is defined as the section $\{g_1h, \ldots, g_mh\}$. This is again a section because of the  (right) action of $h$ on $G/N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are considering sections as sets, lets look at when an orbit is shorter, that is if an element $g$ stabilizes a particular section. That means that any section element $n_r\sigma(r)$ is mapped to another section element, that is $n_r\sigma(r)\cdot g=n_{r\cdot \bar g}\sigma(r\cdot \bar g)$, respectively 
$$
n_{r\cdot \bar g}=n_r\sigma(r)\cdot g/\sigma(r\cdot \bar g).
$$
This implies that a section stabilizer may not have two different elements $g_1,g_2$ with same image in the factor group $\overline{g_1}=\overline{g_2}$, that is the candidates for section stabilizers are the subgroups that intersect trivial with $N$.
Such subgroups act semiregularly on $G/N$ and the formula aboves prescribes section values with choices for each orbit of the subgroup.

Comment: If I understand correctly this resumes to: if a element of the stabilizer group leaves a set invariant (by right action) it never fixes an element of that group

Comment: @MarcBogaerts Yes, apart from the identity.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote "group" instead of "set" at the end of  my comment.

Comment: So, to answer my question, I would take a group $S$ intersecting $N$ trivially. $S$ acts on the cosets defining a partition $\mathcal{P}$ on it. Then I would take a random representative $g_i$ from each member of $\mathcal{P}$. The other elements of the section would be determined by $n_sg_is, s  \in S$, with $n_s$ calculated using the formula from your answer. A question remains, that is, how can this efficiently be realized in GAP?